# I'm trying to add the following scripts to the head of a website but it gives me 404 error

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, performance, jquery-plugins

My code below is how I add the jquery-3.5.1.min.js to the head of the website along with embeddedCPC.js

```
var scriptOne = document.createElement("script");
  var scriptTwo = document.createElement("script");

  scriptOne.setAttribute('src', '/scripts/api/vendor/jquery-3.5.1.min.js')
  scriptTwo.setAttribute('src', '/scripts/embeddedCPC.js')

  document.head.appendChild(scriptOne);
  document.head.appendChild(scriptTwo);
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Use the correct URL ‍♂️

Comment: You need to make sure that your file exists on this URL `https://www.currys.co.uk/scripts/api/vendor/jquery-3.5.1.min.js`, if it's there then need to allow it to be served through the server

Comment: @FadiHania How can I allow it to be served through the server? Does this need to be done in the back end?

Comment: Post more details about your server technology, and code to be able to help. It's different if it's Node.js, PHP, ASP.NET or any other tech

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you don't have the files under those addresses on the server

Comment: How can I allow it to be served through the server? Does this need to be done in the back end?

Comment: Yeah, you need access to the server (via ftp example), then you can see the whole file structure and just put it in the right place/folder